# Confused about raabe's test conditions

Tags: calculus

In my textbook, Advanced calculus by angus e taylor, the conditions for raabe's test stated that "Suppose that the limit $n(1-\frac{U_(n+1)}{U_n})$ exists (either as a finite limit or as +infinity or -infinity).    So my question is that so when would the limit not exist? Since isnt a limit either finite or infinite??

Comment: $a_n = (-1)^n$. There is no limit.

Comment: oh right... i totally forgot about that, thanks alot!!